# Saving dataframe records in a tab delimited file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How can I save records of a `DataFrame` into a tab delimited output file?
The `DataFame` looks like below:

```
>>> csvDf.show(2,False)

1. |1  |Eldon Base for stackable storage shelf, platinum  |Muhammed
MacIntyre|3  |-213.25|38.94 |35   |Nunavut|Storage & Organization   
|0.8 | 
2. |2  |1.7 Cubic Foot Compact "Cube" Office Refrigerators|Barry
French      |293|457.81 |208.16|68.02|Nunavut|Appliances            
|0.58|
```

Answer (score 15):

Just pass `delimiter` option to the writer:

```
csvDf.write.option("delimiter", "\t").csv(output_path)
```

In Spark 1.6 use [`spark-csv` package](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) (check `README` for detailed instructions) with the same option:

```
csvDf.write.option("delimiter", "\t").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(output_path)
```

Comment: i am using spark 1.6, i believe it doesn't have the csv option for dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

In Spark 2.4.3 it is:

```
csvDf
.write
.option("sep", "\t")
.option("encoding", "UTF-8")
.csv(targetFilePath)
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me ...

> > > csvDf.rdd.map(lambda x: '\t'.join(x)).coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile('/output/csv/6.csv')

Comment: Using coalesce in this way will do re-partitioning of the dataframe to one partition which if bigger than JVM can lead to memory overflow issues.